# How to use a second GPU for dedicated computing?

Tags: amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I have got two GPUs on my workstation (AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2990WX): (i) Ellesmere and (ii) Vega 10 XT. While Ellesmere is used for normal display, Vega 10XT is just sitting idle as I do not know how to use it.

I would like to use Vega 10XT solely for scientific computing such as running simulations (mainly, LAMMPS) and data analysis (using OpenACC). I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How much monitors do you have attached to your workstation? Which software should use your Vega card?

Comment: There is just one monitor (Dell 24inch) attached to the workstation.
I want to use Vega card for two purposes: (i) running molecular dynamics simulations using LAMMPS, HOOMD etc. (ii) run in-house fortran codes for solving stochastic differential equations with OpenACC interface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's seemed that this is more particular application question than Ubuntu question. Or maybe AMD related question which could be answered in posts like https://developer.amd.com/spack/hpc-applications-lammps/ or the same ones. Better ask in say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lammps

Comment: @Serg Thank you for _spak_ link. I shall ask around there.
I was redirected here from _stackoverflow_

Comment: Hm, sorry. Maybe better idea is to get one definite product and try to make it work with your hardware. If you expect any problems your question will be not so general and highly possibly will have answer. If you make it work you solve root problem and another ones should work too.